# How to remove ?limitstart=0 after .html?

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, url

Is there any way to remove `?limitstart=0` from the website URL using htaccess or jQuery?

My URLs now looks like `/something.html?limitstart=0`

I want those to look like `/something.html`, without `?limitstart=0` at the end of the URL.

Thanks.

Comment: Removing them from the URL using JS is a bit late in the cycle to be of any benefit. Wouldn't it make more sense to remove them from the source?

Comment: its rather the question what is adding that parameter if not you

Comment: ?limitstart=0 is generated by some Joomla third-part component, I know which component is it, but I don't know which file of this component hold this. There are a lot of files. Maybe will be faster to remove it using JS.
Thank you for your answer.